# python twitter libraries - which one to use?

Tags: python, twitter, libraries

I want to extract information from Twitter using Python. There is a page with several twitter libraries:

https://dev.twitter.com/docs/twitter-libraries

Now I am not sure which one to use. Does anyone has experiences with them? I tried Twython and it is easy to handle but are the others worth a try too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tweepy is worth a go as it quite conveniently wraps the User, Tweet, Status etc... into easily accessible Python objects. The other one I've used is plain python-twitter, which does make interfacing easier, but is closer to raw bones JSON queries, and you have to remember the correct URLs to query. IIRC, both support standard interactions and the ability to use the tracking and searching engines.

Have a look on http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=twitter&submit=search for other options - but it really depends what you want to do and how. I've had success with the aforementioned but I can't recommend any *ideal* Python twitter library.

Answer (score 1):

I have spent the past few weeks working with Twitter-Python -- the one hosted through Google. I really like the library, although I have not used tweepy or twython. I am pretty new to Python and I have find using Twitter-Python to be very intuitive and easy -- the library has tons of methods to return pretty much any data point you want. It can be a bit daunting since it's a lot of code, but once you get familiar with the library I think it's really simple to use. As the other users have noted though, Twitter-Python doesn't have a streaming API (as far as I know), so if you need that use tweepy.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what exactly you want to do. Twython is good and is regularly updated as well. Besides that,

Python Tweeter should take care of most of the stuff you would want to achieve. Plus, it's easy and fun to use.

If you need some sort of streaming API support, Tweepy is what you should go for.